# "Deploy as instant app" checkbox is disabled

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-3.0

I've set the `<dist:module dist:instant="true" />` in the manifest and now I'd like to build an instant app directly to the emulator, but it seems the checkbox is disabled. Any ideas to why?

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Download the latest version of this SDK from the SDK Tools tab within the Android SDK Manager. And after do File/Invalidate Caches and Restart.
That helped me.

Comment: As usual, Google's instructions leave out critical steps.

Answer (score 1):

In my case with Android Studio 3.3.1, i had to create a new configuration and that had the checkbox enabled. The default configuration has it disabled.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to fix this by updating the Android Gradle Plugin to 3.3.0+ (specifically, 3.3.2). I was on Android Studio 3.3 but had not yet updated the Gradle plugin.